# Is it legal to trade between markets when there are market inefficiencies?

Tags: ether, legal

Are there regulations or rules that prevent me from writing a program that profits from arbitrage?

For example: Coinbase may be selling ETH for $99 and Kraken $90 which provides an outstanding opportunity for arbitrage profits of around 10% by buying on Kraken and immediately selling on Coinbase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is generally not illegal for an individual to arbitrage between crypto-currency exchanges, and many people have done this without legal problems. However, the laws that apply to you will depend on which jurisdiction you live in, as do the tax liabilities you may incur.

Another risk you should be aware of is that if you're moving large amounts of money through a personal bank account it's possible that your bank may find your activity suspicious. Depending how helpful they are they may ask you to explain your transactions, or they may simply close your account.

Finally, be aware that there are already experienced people arbitraging between exchanges, so if there is a large, persistent gap between them that has not already been arbitraged away, there is often a reason for it. For example, at one point it was possible to earn money easily by buying bitcoins, selling them on Mt Gox, withdrawing Japanese Yen to a Japanese bank account, converting the Yen to USD, and using the USD to buy more bitcoins. Then one day it was no longer possible to withdraw the Japanese Yen.

Answer (score 1):

No you can do whatever you want. Take deposit and withdrawal fees into account and also transactions fees.